# If current value is not a value within an array, then print text

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am trying to print a sequence of numbers which are not in an array.

Something like this might do I think:

```
<script>
p = [3, 7, 19, 22, 5];
for (var i = 0; i <= 30 && i != (p array values); i++){
    $('body').append(i)
    }; 
</script>
```

Comment: So this is what you did, now What's the issue?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple loop:

```js
p = [3, 7, 19, 22, 5];
for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
  if (p.indexOf(i) === -1) { // not exist in the array
    $('body').append(i + ", ");
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```

> The `indexOf()` method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

See [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). It's a very handy method in native JS.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I think you're trying to do (print the numbers from 0 to 30 that are NOT part of your array).

```js
var p = [3, 7, 19, 22, 5];
for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
    if ($.inArray(i, p) === -1) $('body').append(i + " ");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since you've already included jQuery, I use [jQuery's inArray function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) to determine if the value is part of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it in an if statement.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/7oybwnvk/) is a working fiddle.

```
p = [3, 7, 19, 22, 5];
for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
 if($.inArray(i, p) == -1){
        $("body").append(i + "<br>");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try the jQuery.inArray() function, it'll return -1 if it doesn't find the value in the array =)

```
<script>
    p = [3, 7, 19, 22, 5];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 30; i++){
        if($.inArray( i , p) == -1){
            $('body').append(i)
        }            
    }; 
</script>
```